# img tag nested in a tag: size problem for the 1st a tag

Tags: html, image, anchor

I nested one img tag into one a tag. Here is the html:

```css
img {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

section a:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <a href="https://www.adelaide.edu.au/" target="_blank">
    <img src="../image/soccerAndWorldCup.jpeg" alt="uniAdelaideLogo">
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/" target="_blank">
          w3school
         </a>
</section>
```

It seems that the image is not wrapped in the 1st tag. Instead, it is below the image [the 1st a tag is below the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlHTA.png). However, its dimension is correctly set when I tried to inspect it[the dimension of the 1st a tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kziTU.png). The margin of the image is correct[correct image margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIM9N.png).

Could someone help to explain why? Many thanks.
A quick complement: is this because anchor tag is inline element and img behaves like inline-block element? I tried display: inline-block for the 1st a tag and the image is wrapped. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display: inline` ignores the `width` and `height` properties; `inline-block` does not.

So if you keep the `a` at its default `inline`, its width will be solely determined by its content (the `img` inside) and its height will be the default for one line. Since the whole of the box will be higher than that though, the `a` will appear to sit at the bottom of the `img` (inside the img's margin). In reality, the `img` is in  the `a`, but overflows out of it.

Does that explain things?

Comment: Many thanks. So it seems that my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's a whitespace issue here. The browser renders a single space for every row of spaces/tabs between tags.

Try this:

```
<section><a href="https://www.adelaide.edu.au/" target="_blank"><img src="../image/soccerAndWorldCup.jpeg" alt="uniAdelaideLogo"></a><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/" target="_blank">w3school</a></section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried that and it seems that it is not working. Thank you all the same. The display: inline-block works. Just want to double check if this is the correct understanding or it is just a coincidence.